# Concatenate variable name with Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I try to concatenate a variable name but it does not work as expected:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/
var jc[[${f.hash}]];
/*]]>*/</script>
```

Result: `var jc'e4407ca0c7899e91403e94719d132c3c5d31c87cf5b3b60a1a7daecc8dff3360';`

Expected: `var jce4407ca0c7899e91403e94719d132c3c5d31c87cf5b3b60a1a7daecc8dff3360;`

Comment: Generally inline scripting use to get the value of a variable instead of variable name itself. `f.hash` is a string variable so it renders with `'` as prefix and suffix. What are you trying to achieve using this value as variable ?

Comment: Are you sure you really need to declare a variable with a "variable" name? What is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to declare a variable with a name defined by a variable. I can't figure out why, but in case that really is what you want to do:

You could use

```
var hash = [[${f.hash}]];
eval('var jc'+hash);
```

This won't work in strict mode. It also won't work if some security policies are enforced.

If you want to create a variable in the global scope, you can also use

```
var hash = [[${f.hash}]]; 
window['jc'+hash] = undefined; //In browser application
global['jc'+hash] = undefined; //In node.js environment
```

Or if you want to declare a variable in a function

```
this['jc'+hash] = undefined;
```

Note: even though JS sintax allows you all of these options, I don't recommend that you do this, for whatever problem you are having. It is considered a Bad Practice and I am 99% sure it can be done without using weird tricks. Hard-to-maintain code ain't cool. Anyone who reads this will have a hard time understanding why it is there.

Comment: It should work but I don't like to use eval. And my JS will have `eval()` everywhere :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with some work that I was doing where I needed to create a bunch of similar `handler` javascript objects with different names.

I used the following in my javascript code

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
var handler[[${iter.index}]] = new Handler();
...
handler[[${iter.index}]].close();
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

He output was like this:

```
<script>
var handler0 = new Handler();
...
handler0.close();
</script>

<script>
var handler1 = new Handler();
...
handler1.close();
</script>
```

This is exactly what I needed.